# JQuery Modal Popup after window.location

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax, dhtml

Below is the information required for this problem.

default.aspx
/test/default.aspx

When default.aspx loads the user clicks a button which should then redirect to /test/default.aspx. I have the modal popup working just not with the redirect and ideas?

I have tried doing `window.location = "/test/default.aspx";` and using a custom `settimeout` method to call the function but it doesn't work. as soon as the new page loads it disappears or flashes when the new page loads if I make the delay longer.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding. Is the problem that the page is not redirecting to /test/default.aspx, or is it that when the redirect happens, the modal popup goes away?

Comment: The modal window shows the overlay (disabled background) and the close button (rendered in js) however doesn't load the html for the popup, I check if the document is ready using jquery.

The /test/default.aspx page loads successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href="www.google.com";
```